# Complex rails query with ActiveRecord multiple group and order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have several tables

**Poi.rb**

```
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true, optional: true, dependent: :destroy, touch: true
  belongs_to :sleep, -> { where(pois: { poitable_type: 'Sleep' }) }, foreign_key: 'poitable_id'
  belongs_to :town, -> { where(pois: { poitable_type: 'Town' }) }, foreign_key: 'poitable_id'
```

default_scope { includes(:type_poi) }

**Sleep & Town**

```
has_one :poi, as: :poitable, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :type_poi, inverse_of: :sleeps (or :town)
has_many :poi_traces, dependent: :destroy
has_many :traces, through: :poi_traces, class_name: 'Trace'
```

**PoiTrace.rb**

```
class PoiTrace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poi
  belongs_to :trace
end
```

My query :

```
Poi.left_joins(:town, :sleep)
             .joins(:poi_traces)
             .where(poi_traces: { poi_traces: { trace_id: [1, 2] }, length_to_paris: 1_370_000..1_520_000})
             .where(statut: [1, 2], poitable_type: ["Sleep", "Town"])
             .uniq
```

I would like to have :

1. Order by poi_traces.length_to_paris
2. Grouped by pois.master_poi_id 2
3. Ordered by pois.poitable_type (in first poitable_type = "Town")
4. Grouped in each group by poi.poitable.type_poi

| poi_trace.length_to_paris | master_poi_id | poitable_type | poi.poitable.type_poi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1520 | 2 | "Town" | "Town" |
|  | 2 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |
|  | 2 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |
|  | 2 | "Sleep" | "Hotel" |
|  | 2 | "Sleep" | "Hotel" |
|  | 2 | "Sleep" | "Lodge" |
| 1510 | 1 | "Town" | "Town" |
|  | 1 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |
|  | 1 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |
|  | 1 | "Sleep" | "Hotel" |
|  | 1 | "Sleep" | "Hotel" |
|  | 1 | "Sleep" | "Lodge" |
| 1490 | 4 | "Town" | "Town" |
|  | 4 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |
|  | 4 | "Sleep" | "Camping" |

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Have you tried to use `.group` or `.order`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `group` and `order`. And try to make attempts before asking, try explaining what you thought and tried and why it failed, you will learn much more doing this.

```
Poi.left_joins(:town, :sleep)
  .joins(:poi_traces)
  .where(poi_traces: { trace_id: [1, 2], length_to_paris: 1_370_000..1_520_000 })
  .where(statut: [1, 2], poitable_type: ["Sleep", "Town"])
  .order("poi_traces.length_to_paris")
  .group("pois.master_poi_id, pois.poitable_type, pois.poitable.type_poi")
  .order("pois.poitable_type DESC, pois.poitable.type_poi")
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried several solutions with group_by. The difficulty I have is that pois is a polymorphic table (poitable => "Sleep", "Town").
I tried the solution you propose, but I get this error :

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "poitable"
LINE 1: ... GROUP BY pois.master_poi_id, pois.poitable_type, pois.poita...